# Running my java code on multiple servers

Tags: java, hadoop, parallel-processing, mapreduce

I wrote a java code that its running time is awful. I know maybe my code is not efficient and I do not focus on making efficient. At this time the only important thing is running my code faster. I have access to a cluster with more than 20 nodes. The following is an schema of that part of my code that takes too much time to run. The first for loop iterations is totally independent from each other.

```
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 10000; j++) {
            HashSet temp1 = new HashSet();
            for (int k = 0; k < 10; k++) {
                HashSet temp2 = new HashSet();
                boolean isSubset = temp1.containsAll(temp2);
                if (isSubset == true) {
                    BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("input.txt"));
                    HashSet temp3 = new HashSet();
                    for (int l = 0; l < 10000; l++) {
                        boolean isSubset1 = temp1.containsAll(temp3);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Based on my basic knowledge of distributed computing, I can run it on multiple servers to get the results faster and also I think MapReduce is another idea. I do not have any experience of parallel processing. I need some ideas and directions how can I parallelize it? Is there any platform to make it parallel? MapReduce is a good idea? Hopefully you can help me with some ideas, tutorial or similar examples. Thanks.

Comment: 10 to the 11th power iterations - I think you'll need a lot of machines

Comment: @KevinDTimm: You are right! I have access to more than 20 servers. Hopefully it is enough.

Comment: can be actually higher than that i think depending how often `isSubset` is true

Comment: @dardo: usually one time out of 10.

Comment: What on earth is this code supposed to do?

Comment: Why do you use two outer for loops, but you don't use either of their index variables.  Why are you creating new HashSets, never adding anything to them, and doing contains on them?  What is in input.txt?  Why are you creating yet another 3rd hash set, then iterating over it 10000 times....

Comment: @aglassman: This code suppose to predict protein structures. As I mentioned before, I'm not looking for an exact solution that is not possible. I'm looking for a general idea to solve it and put this code to just give an idea to readers about the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For better performance - you should use threads

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Based on my knowledge, using threads means some parts of my job will be processed concurrently in one CPU. Am I right? If so, is it possible to use threads on multiple connected servers?

Answer (score 0):

To use MapReduce you first to partition (map) the problem into subsets which are provided to the actual processor (Reducer).  These are then joined together after all the mapped inputs are finished processing.

That said, you have more problems than throwing CPU at it, this algorithm is super slow, and figuring out how to map the input into key-value pairs to be used with something like Hadoop will require some major refactoring.

Can read up on the basics of Hadoop from the Mapper class alone:

[Apache Hadoop Mapper](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/Mapper.html)

Comment: I'm totally agree with you. I'm looking for some similar examples to get some ideas how to convert it into mapreduce jobs.

Comment: I certainly think this problem can't be expressed in map/reduce (somewhat efficiently). But I can't see the whole code, just some very strange fragments.

Comment: @ThomasJungblut: Because the whole code is about 15000 lines and other parts are fast enough.